# WPF DataGrid SelectedRow only text in data cells is highlighted

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a simple DataGrid in my WPF app (Window) and when a row is selected only the text in the data cells of the row is highlighted (background color) and not the whole row.

How can I get the whole row to be have a background color when highlighted?

[image: Sample DataGrid]

XAML for the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPodatki"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectionChanged="dgPodatki_SelectionChanged"
          MouseDoubleClick="dgPodatki_MouseDoubleClick"
          CanUserAddRows="false"
          IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        ...

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Check you cell templates, may be you are overriding default styling.

Comment: I use this in three of the columns:
`<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
   <Style>
      <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment"
                   Value="Right" />
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>`

Comment: Keep HorizontalAlignment to Stretch and set TextAlignment to Right.

Comment: Following your suggestion the "highlighting" problem is solved, but then text in the cells gets left aligned, not right...?

Comment: That is because FtameworkElement does not have TextAlignment propety, change FrameworkElement to TextBlock and see if things change!

Comment: OK. Thank you. This worked best:
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply style to individual columns, set your style to :

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Alternatively, you can change your `CellStyle` to:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```